How To Do Clustering Based on Three Variables in R?
I would like to cluster different illnesses (rownames) based on their mean scores on three variables (sociability, morality, competence). How to do that and which clustering method is the best here in your opinion ?



Rownames (Illnesses)
Competence
Sociability
Morality




Epilepsy
2
1
3


Gastritis
4
3
3


MS
5
4
2



I tried to do a PCA and a normal 3D scatterplot but I dont know if those two are adequate.
